# Laravel DD prints right variable but 'non-object'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've encountered a strange error when using laravel. So essentially when I call this

```
{{ $product->images()->first()->fileName }}
```

I get the following error

```
Trying to get property 'fileName' of non-object
```

However, when I call it in dd it shows the variable fine...

```
@dd($product->images()->first()->fileName);
```

So I'm not really sure whats wrong, 'images' is related by a hasMany call in product. Would love some advice on whats going on here!

Comment: please post the view code, without context is really difficult to understand what is going on

Comment: dd() will stop it on the first execution. You likely are iterating over products, and one of them does not have an image

Comment: @KurtFriars That is exactly it! Thank you, is there anyway if it doesn't exact to return nothing in blade?

Comment: @VSLover333 you can try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple, but not necessarily ideal solution:

```
@php $image = $product->images()->first(); @endphp 
@if($image)
<img src="{{ $image->fileName }}"/>
@endif
```

Comment: I've found the better way to do this is 

    @if(isset($product->images()->first()->fileName))
        {{$product->images()->first()->fileName}}
    @endif

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are iterating over the products, one of the products must not have an image.

Without changing your code much, just add an `@` before the statement

```
{{ @$product->images()->first()->fileName }}
```

This will automatically handle the error and return null. So, your program won't crash.

See [PHP Error Control Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: This is a really cool answer, I did not know about the @ operator. But I am assuming they probably want to handle the case the image is empty.